# Carousel in angular does not work unless I click refresh

Tags: angular, carousel, refresh

I am doing a small project using angular with api and part of the project is to display images using carousel. Basically, I have a page "Gallery" with a list of places, and once the user clicks on a certain place, all the images of that place are showed.. This works as I have tested it without carousel.. Even with carousel it works, however, only when I refresh after I click on the place. In other words, when I click on a place, I get shown the active image of the carousel but it does not show the other images.. However, if I click on a place (and go to its images) and click refresh, I get the active image and the the next image, etc, meaning works perfectly.. I even showed it to my lecturer who tried debugging it for 1 hour and did not know what the problem is.. Would be great if I get to know what the problem is.. Thanks!

```
<h1 class="text-center bg-secondary text-white py-2 m-0">{{placeFromUrl}}</h1>
<div class="card bg-primary">
<div class="card-body">
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/cf/Angular_full_color_logo.svg/250px-Angular_full_color_logo.svg.png" class="d-block w-50 mx-auto">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let image of placeImages">
                <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{image.bytes}}" class="d-block w-50 mx-auto">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>    
</div>
<a class="btn btn-secondary col-md-12 mb-2" routerLink='/gallery' routerLinkActive="active">{{'HOME.backToList' | translate}}</a>
```

Comment: Is `Carousel` a third party library?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure.. I just searched it on bootstrap and used it

Comment: Are you added bootstrap package on your angular project?

Comment: Also you must change the src attribute and use it with this syntax <img src="{{'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + image.bytes}}" />

Comment: @pichlou I added bootstrap yes and the conversation is correct because I used it before.. This is something related to carousel

Comment: That is better you install the ng-bootstrap or ngx-bootstrap package and use it's carousel in your component.

Comment: The problem is not carousel itself because it works IF I refresh.. it just doesn't work if I just click on a place and go to its images

Comment: Would you create a stackblitz demo?

Comment: @RickAstley Did you figure this out?  I have the same issue with an angular app. The carousel only functions after a page refresh.